# How to save textbox value in the database

Tags: google-app-maker

How to save textbox value in the database
[image: How to save textbox value in the database] 
(Textbox  value populated based on other textbox input value)

Comment: Since you are already using the createMode datasource, I believe the "Create" button saves the record. You can just simply open the on click event editor and add `widget.datasource.item.TotalRate = textbox4value`, or whatever the field is called for TotalRate, before the line that creates the item.

Comment: Other possibility would be to bind the textbox value to your datasource item and for the onValueChange or onValueEdit event of your other two textboxes set your item.TotalRate. In this case I would also suggest to set your TextBox4 to 'ViewOnlyIfDissabled' and then in the property editor uncheck 'enabled'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions proposed in comments to the question seem to be reasonable, but I would offer one more if you don't mind. If `TotalRate` field's value is somehow important/vulnerable then I would never store it in database to avoid possible malicious manipulations from app users. In case there is some good reason/requirement to store calculated value in database I would go with calculation on the server side and handle it in `onBeforeCreate` and `onBeforeSave` [model events](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events):

```javascript
// onBeforeCreate/onBeforeSave event handlers
record.TotalRate = record.PerHourRate * record.HoursNumber;
```